# Pointer parameter with JNI

Tags: c, function, pointers, java-native-interface

I've got function from dll file with my RFID reader.

```
long WINAPI OpenComPort(long* Port, unsigned char *ComAddr , unsigned char *Baud,long *FrmHandle)
```

i don't have any idea for sent parameter from java to this function. I were try many type of parameter but this fail. Please teach me send parameter to this function.

sry if my english is hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass an Java object to your JNI function, and create the corresponding struct in there and fill it. Then you can pass a pointer to this struct to your WinAPI function. Maybe JNA is a quicker solution than writing a JNI library.